# Extract numbers after TAB with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I need to process a text file which contains data in the format:

```
# "#"      131
$ "$"      6492
```

and so on. I am interested only in the numbers inside this file and after the first two columns are is a tab after which come the numbers I am interested in. How can I achieve this in a new file with only numbers using grep functionality? Many thanks!

Comment: Just the 3rd column or from the 3rd column up to the end?

Comment: Just the 3rd columns which also happens to be the last column, the end of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is easier with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print $3}' file
131
6492
```

Or even `cut`:

```
$ cut -d$'\t' -f3 file
131
6492
```

In both cases, `tab` is defined as the field separator and then the 3rd field is printed.

Comment: Yes, awk should be better. However, when I try to use the command I get empty lines instead of the lines with numbers. Also, it is possible to write the results to another file?

Comment: Make sure it is a real tab what separated the fields. Regarding writing the results into another file, just redirect the output: `cut -d$'\t' -f3 file > output_file`.

Comment: Yes, it works now, the thing that made the difference was that I needed to print $2 as the third column, that's why I was getting those blank lines as output! However, your reply was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk '{print $3}' file
131
6492
```

or

```
awk '{print $NF}' file
```